# Store Products and Store Orders issues of Commerce_marketplace module

Tags: commerce

I want to create a marketplace site(where multiple merchants/ stores will add their products to our site.) using Drupal Commerce and commerce_marketplace module. But i am having issues with this. Store owner is unable to find his/her added products.

Is there alternative way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to user/%/store(or by clicking the stores tab in your user page), you will be able to see the stores of the particular user. On clicking the store name, you will be re-directed to a page commerce_store/store/%storeid.
In this page, there will be diffrerent tabs View, Edit, Delete, "Storename"'s products, Memebers and Sales tab.

On clicking the tab "Storename"'s products, you will be able to see the products added to your store.

Also please double check that you have enabled correct permissions.

One thing though, admin will not be able to see the products of another user via the above method. He will have to naviagate to structure->Entity type -> commerce store ->store and click on a particular store name to view that store's details.

Let me know how that goes.